# Twitter feed doesn't show all its just a link

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I created a Twitter widget but I don't know how to import it in my HTML code, it only shows a link then.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/timelines/539487832448843776">
National Park Tweets - Curated tweets by TwitterDev
</a>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

It doesn't shows the things around it.

Any help?

Comment: Are you testing your code by "double-click" opening the `.html` file by any chance? I mean the URL in your browser starts by `file:///`

Comment: Yes im using that why :/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code inside of a div like so

```
<div><a class="twitter-timeline" 
href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/timelines/539487832448843776">National 
Park Tweets - Curated tweets by TwitterDev</a> <script async 
src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: It works even without wrapping it in a div, so I don't understand the point of this answer: https://jsfiddle.net/5fnvyxLo/3/

Answer (score 0):

When opening the webpage without a local server(opening the file directly in the browser) you are using the `file://` protocol, which is based on your local file system.

You are importing Twitter's script by using `//`

```
<script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js">
```

which means *"use the current protocol"*. This is used for not wondering whether the website uses `http` or `https`, avoiding issues when importing http resources in a https website.

**This is a problem, because Twitter's script is in the Internet, not on your local file system.**

> Change manually the script `src` protocol to `http` or `https`(preferably) so it script can be
>   retrieved.

```
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```